# Unable to resize Image retrieved from database in MVC

Tags: html, css, model-view-controller

I'm retrieving an image from database stored in bytes array. It works fine and displays correctly on the browser but I can't resize it. 
I have tried using ***'width', style="width:",inline, internal css, external css, !important***.
This is how I'm storing data including image to database.

```
public ActionResult registerFormData(registerForm form, HttpPostedFileBase imageFile)
        {

            form.Image = new byte[imageFile.ContentLength];
            imageFile.InputStream.Read(form.Image, 0, imageFile.ContentLength);
            form.imageType = imageFile.ContentType;

            var data = _context.registerForms.SingleOrDefault(f => f.name == form.name);
            if (data == null)
            {
                _context.registerForms.Add(form);
                _context.SaveChanges();

                TempData["message"] = "Your Account has been created";
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
                TempData["message"] = "A user with this name already exist. Choose other name";
            return RedirectToAction("registerForm", "Home");
```

This is my action in controller class to retrieve image.(Works fine)

```
public ActionResult getImage()
{
      registerForm data = _context.registerForms.SingleOrDefault(f => f.name == "abc");
      return new FileContentResult(data.Image, data.imageType);

}
```

This is where I'm displaying image right now just to test.

```
<div class="item" >

     <img src="@Url.Action("getImage", "Home")/>
 </div>
```

Is there a way to resize image.

Comment: Have you try adding !iimportant to your css, example img {width:100%!important}

Comment: As i mentioned in my question, yes i did. Nothing worked.

Comment: Is your code working in any place where I can see?, I mean the resulting HTML

Comment: Code is working fine. It is displaying the image. But it displays image in one size(Original size). I want to make it small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
made slight changes in My Action.

From

```
public ActionResult getImage()
{
      registerForm data = _context.registerForms.SingleOrDefault(f => f.name == "abc");
      return new FileContentResult(data.Image, data.imageType);

}
```

To

```
public ActionResult getImage()
        {
            registerForm data = _context.registerForms.SingleOrDefault(f => f.name == "abc");
            ViewBag.Base64String = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(data.Image, 0, data.Image.Length);
            return View(data);

        }
```

And in my view changed

From

```
<img src="@Url.Action("getImage", "Home")/>
```

To

```
 <img alt="" src="@ViewBag.Base64String"/>
```

Now, All CSS properties are working and I can resize my image.